# Wireless signal reflection/absorption on different materials

Tags: rf, signal-theory

I'm trying to understand the characteristics of RF signals/waves in different environments. I am wondering if there is any data out there regarding how much a wireless signal reflect from an object or get absorbed by it.

Would this be tabulated under common items such as metals, wood, and concrete? (I'm less concerned with water) I'm mainly interested in 2.45 Ghz, but it might be interesting to look at other frequencies.

If no one knows of a tabulated form, here is the alternative question:
What causes RF waves to reflect or absorb? Does the reflective/absorptive property of RF waves act similarly to light properties? Are permittivity and permeability in electromagnetism causing the reflection/absorption? If yes to the last question, could you elaborate how it is (since Wikipedia only describes when the object is the medium forming the waves, not as the receiver)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What causes RF waves to reflect or absorb?
>   The material, more specifically if its conductive or not.

If the material is perfectly conductive you get a reflection which follows snells law. If the material is not conductive you get some of the wave that does not get reflected and enters the material, at which point it probably get attenuated. 
[image]
Source: [Antennas](http://slideplayer.com/slide/8361563/)

Take for example a wall, the boundary between the air and the wall causes a reflection, and some of the wave enters the material of the wall. The wall has an impedance, which means some of the wave will also get absorbed (ohmic losses, not shown in the equations below). And then more relfection on the way out.

[image]

> Does the reflective/absorptive property of RF waves act similarly to
>   light properties?
>   Yes very similar, infact the optics equations can be derived from electromagnetic equations. The differences are the frequencies and the materials.

Usually we use seperate equations in optics and in electromagnetics, because of the difficulty of working with these equations. Usually ohmic losses in RF are from

As your questions stand they are probably too broad for the scope of this site, however, I took a crack at answering them anyway. If your really interested in this, then pick up any Electromagnetics Theory book.

Comment: The slideshow that you shared made things more complicated for me. I had no idea that the incident angle changes reflectivity. I was indeed hoping for a more general approach, but I guess the solution is too complex to write in a single general equation. I didn't even consider diffracted, refracted and scattered waves.

Comment: So the way how a Faraday cage works is by reflecting electromagnetic waves? For some reason (I haven't studied much electrical subject except digital logics and basic circuitry) I assumed that the waves traveled through the cage into ground, as in the cage absorbed the electricity and grounded it.

Comment: It depends! Some of the power is still reflected, but yes, materials can also function as antennas especially conductors. There is no simple answer, and a lot of times the physical world is vastly more complex than just a few equations. Most of the time I ditch the equations and use experimentation when it comes to RF because it would take longer to calculate what is happening with RF than to actually test it.

Comment: The secret of stealth-fighters was from a Russian paper, on how edges of metals cause the diffractions. The Lockheed guys ran with that, and cranked out the theories. Thus "shielding" is a complex topic.

Comment: Yes, books are written on the subject